# Change a foreign key to null from not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is needed for my project but I just need to know how to take a foreign key in sql that is set as a not null column and make it a null column without dropping anything. I have a large dataset that is referenced here but, going forward, I want to not have the fk as a mandatory column.

Comment: What database are you using? And, of course, what did you consider?

Comment: Simple use 

Alter Table table_name
Alter Column column_name datatype

without mentioning foreign key constraint as below
Alter Table table_name
Alter Column column_name datatype foreign key references ref_table(ref_table_col)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming MySQL here and an INT column named `col`, you could do this like so:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY col INT NULL
```

ETA: For SQL Server, would look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN col INT NULL
```

Comment: I said I was using sql like as in ssms. SQL Server 2008 r2 to be exact. For me this says incorrect syntax near modify

Answer (score 0):

Simple use

```
Alter Table table_name Alter Column column_name datatype
```

without mentioning foreign key constraint as below

```
Alter Table table_name Alter Column column_name datatype foreign key references ref_table(ref_table_col)
```